# Dynamic Pivot query to View/Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, view, pivot

After a lot of work I managed to create a dynamic pivot query with the results I want.

Now I need to be able to send parameters and filter my query. Normally I just create a view where I can use a `SELECT * FROM` and in `WHERE` clause use my parameters to filter. I read that it's not possible to create a view from a dynamic pivot query so I need help to solve this problem.

This is my SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(p.tag)
                   FROM (((ZUS_Monatsreport_Kopf k
                   LEFT JOIN ZUS_Monatsreport_Pos p ON k.Id = p.Id_Kopf)  
                   LEFT JOIN ADR_Adressen a ON k.Adresse = a.AdressNrADR)  
                   LEFT JOIN ADR_GruppenLink gl ON a.AdressNrADR = gl.AdressNrADR)  
                   LEFT JOIN ADR_Gruppen g ON gl.GruppeADR = g.GruppeADR 
                   GROUP BY p.Tag
                   ORDER BY p.tag
                   FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = 'SELECT AdressNrADR,Monat,Id_kopf,Name,Artikel, '+ @cols + ' FROM
            (
                SELECT a.AdressNrADR,k.monat,p.Id_kopf,a.name + '' ''+ a.vorname as Name,p.Artikel, p.Tag,CASE WHEN CAST(p.wert  AS VARCHAR(10)) = '''' THEN CAST(p.Menge AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE CAST(p.Wert AS VARCHAR(10)) END AS Menge 
                FROM   ( ( ( ZUS_Monatsreport_Kopf k
                LEFT JOIN  ZUS_Monatsreport_Pos p ON k.Id =  p.Id_Kopf)  
                LEFT JOIN  ADR_Adressen a ON k.Adresse =  a.AdressNrADR)  
                LEFT JOIN  ADR_GruppenLink gl ON a.AdressNrADR =  gl.AdressNrADR)  
                LEFT JOIN  ADR_Gruppen g ON gl.GruppeADR =  g.GruppeADR 
            ) x
             pivot
             ( max(menge)
                for tag in (' +@cols +')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

This is how my result looks like:

[image]

Now I need to be able to make a select around the this SQL and say for example

```
SELECT * 
FROM mypivotquery
WHERE AdressNrADR = 10640 (<-parameter) and Monat = 2 (<-parameter)
```

I hope I could explain what I'm looking for and that you guys can help me :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add where condition in dynamic query, change your `SET @Query` statement to,

```
SET @query = 'SELECT AdressNrADR,Monat,Id_kopf,Name,Artikel, '+ @cols + ' FROM
        (
            SELECT a.AdressNrADR,k.monat,p.Id_kopf,a.name + '' ''+ a.vorname as Name,p.Artikel, p.Tag,CASE WHEN CAST(p.wert  AS VARCHAR(10)) = '''' THEN CAST(p.Menge AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE CAST(p.Wert AS VARCHAR(10)) END AS Menge 
            FROM   ( ( ( ZUS_Monatsreport_Kopf k
            LEFT JOIN  ZUS_Monatsreport_Pos p ON k.Id =  p.Id_Kopf)  
            LEFT JOIN  ADR_Adressen a ON k.Adresse =  a.AdressNrADR)  
            LEFT JOIN  ADR_GruppenLink gl ON a.AdressNrADR =  gl.AdressNrADR)  
            LEFT JOIN  ADR_Gruppen g ON gl.GruppeADR =  g.GruppeADR 
            WHERE a.AdressNrADR = 10640 (<-parameter) and Monat = 2 (<-parameter)
        ) x
            pivot
            ( max(menge)
            for tag in (' +@cols +')
        ) p '
```